# SignalR design concept

Tags: design

I'm creating a work diary web application in mvc using vb.net The application will display any diary entries that have a HiLite boolean field (HL) set to true in a table on the home page.

Currently I've implemented a simple refresh of the home page using a meta tag that refreshes the page every 2 mins and this copes with any changes to the table. e.g. a new HiLited diary entry has been added by someone or a HiLited entry has had its flag set false.

I would like to 'move with the times' and possibly use SignalR to eliminate unnecessary requests + have a more realtime feel to the table data.

I've not used SignalR before. I've looked at some simple examples but need clarification if this is the best way to go.

Will using SignalR do the following....

1. On first visit get and display all current HL diary entries
2. If a new entry is added refresh the table on all clients
3. If an entry has it's HL flag set to false refresh the table on all clients

or is there some better method.

The SignalR samples I've seen are simple 'chat' samples that basically have two params User + Msg and the code appends any new messages to an html element.

I will have an list of a diary entry object... will I be able to do what I need and instead of appending to html element... I use it to replace the content of the html element.

Comment: Recommended reading: **[Why is “Is it possible to…” a poorly worded question?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/7274/31260)**

Comment: @gnat Thanks for the comment... I'm not looking for code all I suppose I want is a sort of confirmation that my consideration to use SignalR will satisfy my requirements...or is there a better method.

Comment: It will do 2 and 3, for 1 I'd suggest just manually calling it and just keeping SignalR for real-time push updates instead.